# making python and fortran friends

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

Assume we need to call fortran function, which returns some values, in python program. I found out that rewriting fortran code in such way:

```
subroutine pow2(in_x, out_x)
      implicit none
      real, intent(in)      :: in_x
!f2py real, intent(in, out) :: out_x
      real, intent(out)     :: out_x
      out_x = in_x ** 2
      return
end
```

and calling it in python in such way:

```
import modulename
a = 2.0
b = 0.0
b = modulename.pow2(a, b)
```

gives us working result. Can I call fortran function in other way, cause I think the first way is a bit clumsy?

Comment: How it can help me? As far as I know it's sort of upgraded interactive mode.

Comment: It also allows you to interface with other programs such as R, MATLAB, and <drumroll /> FORTRAN. Check out [this video](http://pyvideo.org/video/1605/science-and-python-retrospective-of-a-mostly-s)

Comment: what's the problem with what you have?  How do you want to call it?

Comment: @mgilson I suppose there will be situations where I'll need to update lots of fortran code in mentioned way, but I don't want to do it cause I'm not crazy and don't have time to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you just need to change your f2py function signature slightly (so that `out_x` is only `intent(out)` and `in_x` is only `intent(in)`):

```
subroutine pow2(in_x, out_x)
  implicit none
  real, intent(in)   :: in_x
  !f2py real, intent(in) :: in_x
  real, intent(out)     :: out_x
  !f2py real, intent(out) :: out_x
  out_x = in_x ** 2
  return
end subroutine pow2
```

Now compile:

```
f2py -m test -c test.f90
```

Now run:

```
>>> import test
>>> test.pow2(3)   #only need to pass intent(in) parameters :-)
9.0
>>>
```

---

Note that in this case, `f2py` is able to correctly scan the signature of the function *without* the special `!f2py` comments:

```
!test2.f90
subroutine pow2(in_x, out_x)
  implicit none
  real, intent(in)   :: in_x
  real, intent(out)     :: out_x
  out_x = in_x ** 2
  return
end subroutine pow2
```

Compile:

```
f2py -m test2 -c test2.f90
```

run:

```
>>> import test2
>>> test2.pow2(3)   #only need to pass intent(in) parameters :-)
9.0
>>>
```

Comment: Wow, that's awesome! This way even can return multiple variables in tuple! Just because of my curiosity if there are some other tricks I won't tick this answer right now.

Comment: I'm frequently impressed by how easy it is to wrap fortran code with `f2py`.  Because of that, I've never bothered to learn any of the python C API or even `Cython` although at some point I'd like to pick up those skills.

Answer (score 0):

Another benefit to avoiding `intent(inout)` arguments is (with a few other restrictions) the resulting function [can be considered `PURE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813494/pure-subroutines-in-fortran-compiler-optimization). This is related to the no-side-effects approach taken by functional languages and pays off with better optimization and error detection by the Fortran compiler and is especially important for auto-parallelization.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IPython, try magic command, which makes it able to write

```
%%fortran
subroutine pow2(in_x, out_x)
  implicit none
  real, intent(in)   :: in_x
  real, intent(out)     :: out_x
  out_x = in_x ** 2
  return
end subroutine pow2
```

and then simply use this function in your code (without additional imports).